# iPhone is busy: Making iPhone ready for development infinite

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

iPhone is busy: Making iPhone ready for development.

[image]

How to fix this?
I tried upgrading, rebooting, pairing again both mac and iphone.
And nothing helps.

Searching through the internet only points to questions, not solutions, like this:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691452

Comment: were you able to solve it? This is driving me crazy, have this problem for 2 months now. No solution is working. I cant use my iPhone for development

Comment: same problem with iphone 7 ios 15.4.1 & xcode 13.3.1

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: Please upgrade your xcode

Answer (score 2):

[image]

first, disconnect your device and close Xcode. then
***Tap On Apple Logo -> About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage -> Developer***

select all and tap on delete in the developer section or you can run this command on the terminal:
`rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`

then restart Xcode and connect your device again.
its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaipee1 pointed out, it has probably to do with Device Support files. They are coincidentally the same size as the firmware images of these versions, so my guess is that XCode loads the device support files from the connected phone itself (loading them from the internet would take way more time) as part of that making ready process. So maybe your USB connection is very slow: some USB hubs say they support USB3.0, but in fact support only USB1.1, which is extremely slow. I had this issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on my Testing device iPhone 12 which doesn't have SIM. Due to testing, I had to change the date and time, which made some things stop working, including this and the software update.
To fix this issue, I just had to change the Date and time to Set Automatically and restart the device.

Answer (score -1):

This has worked for me:

1- Connect it using USB.
2- Turn off Wifi, bluetooth and celullar network.
3- Disable Connect via network on xcode.
4- Install the app.

Note: Once installed it wont be able to open it until you enable wifi / celullar again, but at that point you should be ready to go!

PD: It's so annying.